# Use Row_Number To Number Records in DB2 (And Reset Count on Change of ID)

Tags: sql, db2, row-number

What I'd like to do is number the records the query returns, but reset the number to 1 on the change of a particular field.  For instance, I would like the Row_Number count to reset back to 1 each time DCACCT changes but increment by 1 when there are multiple records for DCACCT.

The new column would ideally look like this (where the first number is the row_count and the second column is DCACCT):
1 - 11

1 - 13

1 - 14

1 - 18

1 - 24

2 - 24

1 - 27

1 - 28

1 - 29

2 - 29

1 - 33

1 - 39

2 - 39

3 - 39

4 - 39

1 - 40

[image: DB2 Query Results]

I'm trying to use the Row_Number function, but I am receiving an error of
`Function not supported for this query` but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here.  Can I accomplish my goal using this function?

```
SELECT
Row_Number() Over (Order By DCACCT ASC) as row_num,
COMM.DCACCT, COMM.DCATYP, COMM.DCCODE, COMM.DCDESC
FROM P50DATA.DCMTRNL5 COMM
JOIN P50DATA.PACNTSL1 PAT ON COMM.DCACCT=PAT.PACTNO
WHERE
PAT.PLAST NOT IN ('SRC','WELL','EMERGENCY','CONFIRM')
AND COMM.DCCODE IN ('PAT1','PAT2','PAT3','PAT4','PINS','PTRX','MRGF')
ORDER BY COMM.DCACCT;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `partition by` clause:

```
select Row_Number() Over (partition By DCACCT order by DCACCT) as row_num,
```

You might have a preference for the column used for ordering within each `DCACCT` value -- such as a creation date or id -- but this just uses the field itself for an arbitrary ordering.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot tomorrow when i get back to the office.

Comment: Also, would this reset the count after on each `DCACCT` record?

Comment: @MISNole . . . Yes, that is why this is an answer to your question.